# How can I add a where statement on list conditionally in report query?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

How can I add a where statement in iReport query with a condition that a list is not empty:

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN length($P{list}) > 0 THEN table_x.id IN ($P!{list}) END
```

I tried to display the report passing an empty list, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Jasper report has it's own [query system](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/) and I presume your `$P{list}` is a class that extends `java.util.Collection` for example a `java.util.List`, since you state "passing an empty list"

To create a **prepared statement**  `IN` query on `Collection` in jasper report you use:

```
WHERE $X{IN, table_x.id, list}
```

Do note that if list is `null` or it is an empty list this query will return **all** records, see [using-parameters-queries](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/using-parameters-queries)

> JasperReports handles special characters in each value. If the parameter is null or contains an empty list, meaning no value has been set for the parameter, the entire $X{} clause is evaluated as the always true statement “0 = 0”.

To not show any records, you need to add at least one `null` value to the `List` in java before you pass parameter to jasper-report.

```
if (list.isEmpty()){
    list.add(null);
}
```

*Please also note that you should avoid using `$P!{param}` since this creates
an sql through string concatenation an open your application to SQL injection attacks, always try to use prepared statement instead.*

Comment: $X{IN, table_x.id, list} brings me all the record even when the list is not empty !!

Comment: @BillyHope it should not, you can debug the query jasper-report executes by adding `log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter=debug` to your JSS `jasperreports.properties` file

Comment: where can i find properties file

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209436/view-sql-executed-by-jasper-report

Comment: i've added the propreties in options>jasperreports properties and set its value to true

Comment: You should see all the query jasper-report make in log, check what query it is doing and from there you can debug, maybe you have an OR or other stuff that brings out all records.

Comment: You don't see any query in log??, if you don't you have not configured correctly! set to debug whole jasper reports `log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports=DEBUG`

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, try using this:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN length($P{list}) > 0 THEN table_x.id IN ($P!{list}) END) <> ''
```

Comment: <> is not recognized

Comment: @BillyHope I left in the '=' does it work now i have edited it out ?

Comment: `$P{list}` is most probably a `java.util.List` hence class (from question: "list is not empty"), hence the solution posted does not really have sense since you can't do lenght directly on the `java.util.List`.  In jasper-report working with parameters you need to use something similar that I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ELSE` clause is `NULL`, and that is false.  I would recommend avoiding the `CASE`:

```
WHERE length($P{list}) = 0 OR table_x.id IN ($P!{list})
```

Comment: `$P{list}` is most probably a `java.util.List` hence class (from question: "list is not empty"), hence the solution posted does not really have sense since you can't do lenght directly on the `java.util.List`.  In jasper-report working with parameters you need to use something similar that I have posted.

Comment: @PetterFriberg . . . That makes a lot of sense.  Even if the OP's code were syntactically correct, it lacks an `ELSE` clause, so it still wouldn't work.